# Problem with match function in javascript for numeric validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written following function to restrict only numbers with the limit of 2 numbers (below 100).

The first part checks special charters and letters.  I got stuck in `else` part.

And Now I am trying to restrict with only 2 digits numeric number (without decimal). But it doesn't work the logic in below code. I am not allowed to use `input type =number` in `HTML`. The html input type is text

```
 $(".allownumericTwo").on("input", function (evt) {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
         return false;
     else {
         $(this).val($(this).val().match(\d{0,2});
     }
     return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) is not [cancelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable). It also doesn't have a value for key code. What you could do instead is to check if the value is valid and if not reset it to its previous value. You also need to enclose your regex pattern between slashes, i.e. `/^\d{0,2}$/`.

e.g.

```js
var oldValue = $(".allownumericTwo").val();
$(".allownumericTwo").on("input", function(evt) {
  if (this.value.length > 0 && this.value.match(/^\d{0,2}$/) == null) {
    this.value = oldValue;
  } else {
    oldValue = this.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='allownumericTwo'>
```

Comment: This is really helpful and was not knowing about input cancel-able issue

Answer (score -1):

you can use isNumeric()

```
if($(this).val().length < 3)
{
    if($.isNumeric($(this).val())){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This May help.
Do remember the match returns an array.

```js
function printFirstTwoNumbers(val) {
  var regex = /^\d{0,2}/g;;
  console.log(val.match(regex));
  return true;
}
        
        
printFirstTwoNumbers('288.80');
printFirstTwoNumbers('2.80');
printFirstTwoNumbers('29898.80');
printFirstTwoNumbers('300');
```